# implementing Knet using PHP

Tags: payment-gateway, php-java-bridge

I have implemented PHP-Java bridge and it works.

Now i thought of implementing the JSP code of knet in php, but dont know how to call function from PHP.
How to execute following line of code in PHP. Mainly this below line

```
configFile.load(application.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/config.txt"));
```

---

```
Properties configFile = new Properties();       
configFile.load(application.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/config.txt"));    


// set properties
e24PaymentPipe pipe = new e24PaymentPipe();
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: do you have this kit in PHP? I want to implement KNET payment gateway with my PHP based website. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking whether the PHP-Java Bridge is working you can write the above function in PHP as Below:

```
$configFile     = new java("java.util.Properties");
$configFile->load($application->getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/config.txt"));

$epaymentpipe   = new java("com.aciworldwide.commerce.gateway.plugins.e24PaymentPipe");
```